# Parsed xml Dictionary to listbox values

Tags: c#

I am parsing xml file to List. Then I would like to use Currency codes as listbox items.

I have tried to do it with:

```
    private void CurrencyConverter_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var choices = new List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>>();
        listBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(choices, null);
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
        listBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
    }
```

But my list is empty. How to get it working that?

I guess something like `listBox1.DataSource = Dictionary.ToList();` is missing, as being on learning curve I am not so sure how to do that.

Here is my full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace Offer_m_v
{
    public partial class CurrencyConverter : Form
    {
        public CurrencyConverter()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>> GetCurrencyListFromWeb(out DateTime currencyDate)
        {
            List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>> returnList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>>();
            string date = string.Empty;
            using (XmlReader xmlr = XmlReader.Create(@"http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml"))
            {
                xmlr.ReadToFollowing("Cube");
                while (xmlr.Read())
                {
                    if (xmlr.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element) continue;
                    if (xmlr.GetAttribute("time") != null)
                    {
                        date = xmlr.GetAttribute("time");
                    }
                    else returnList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>(xmlr.GetAttribute("currency"), decimal.Parse(xmlr.GetAttribute("rate"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
                }
                currencyDate = DateTime.Parse(date);
            }
            returnList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("EUR", 1));
            return returnList;
        }

        private void CurrencyConverter_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        var choices = new List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>>();
        listBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(choices, null);
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
        listBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // decimal value = (amount / Dictionary[CurrencyFrom]) * Dictionary[CurrencyTo];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you add values to `choices` collection? Also there is no usages of `GetCurrencyListFromWeb` in your code sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string URL = "http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(URL);
            XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            Dictionary<string, decimal> currenciesDict = doc.Descendants(ns + "Cube")
                .Where(x => x.Attribute("currency") != null)
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("currency"), y => (decimal)y.Attribute("rate"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        }


    }
}
```